# Python How to send multiple dataframe as HTML tables in the email body

Tags: python, pandas, email, dataframe

i've split the single dataframe in to 4 dataframes based on the column value and  i want to sent all those dataframes in the email body with proper table formatting, please advise how can i achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to SO!, Can you provide some code to show you tried?

Comment: Hi @Jagdish693 is `df.to_html()` what you wanted? check out the answer, if it is not, I shall remove the answer

Comment: as @lrh09 said you can use `df.to_html()` to get table as HTML. And you can concatenate many tables `df1.to_html() + "<br>" + df2.to_html()`

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should ask question after trying by yourself. Lots of help is there on net.

However you may use these below code snippet to send multiple Data Frame as email. 
Below code is pretty straight forward and hope no explanation is needed.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

def send_mail(cdf):
    df = cdf  # Make anaother DF; in you case you'll may be pass another Data Frame to this function
    sender = "xxx@yy.com"
    receiver = ['xxxx@yy.com']
    msg = MIMEMultipart('related')

    msg['Subject'] = "Subject Here"
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(receiver)
    html = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <p>Hi!<br>
           Here is first Data Frame data:<br>
           {0}
           <br>Here is second Data Frame data:<br>
           {1}

           Regards,
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>

    """.format(cdf.to_html(), df.to_html())

    partHTML = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(partHTML)
    ser = smtplib.SMTP('gateway_server', port_number)
    ser.login("username", "password")
    ser.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `df.to_html()`

```
df = 

   A  B
0  A  C
1  A  G
2  T  T
3  C  G
4  A  A
5  G  G

> print(df.to_html())


<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>T</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```